# Trouble with jQuery Cookie Pop up

Tags: jquery

Hello I am trying to get the correct answer to a jquery question. I have looked on this site and saw some examples but all I have tried do not  work. I have this jquery pop up box and I am trying to have the popup first load with a timer (this I have working). However, most importantly I would like to have the popup only appear once per session. by this I mean if someone visits the site twice or if they click the "x" to close the popup the cookies will prevent the popup from displaying. Bellow is my code. Can someone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<title>Cookies</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
}

.backdrop {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #000;
opacity: .0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
z-index:50;
display:none;   
}

.box {
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 30%;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
overflow-y: scroll;
background: #fff;
z-index: 51;
padding: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
display: none;  
}

.close {
float: right;
margin-right: 6px;
cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

//This function open the box after 10 seconds.  
setTimeout(function(){
$('.lightbox').ready(function(){
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
$('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
$('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block')
});
},10000);   

//This function closes the box
$('.close').click(function(){
$('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
$('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none')
});
});

$('.close').click(function(){
            close_box();

});

$('.backdrop').click(function(){
            close_box();
});
});

function close_box(){

$('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
$('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none')

if($.cookie("lightbox") != 'true') {
 $(".box").hide().trigger('click');
$.cookie("lightbox", "true", { path: '/', expires: null });  
    }
  });
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="backdrop"></div>
<div class="box"><div class="close">X</div>
      Light box</div>

</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML markup too? Why an oldish jQuery 1.4.2 version?

Comment: OK thanks Irvin. I have edited my original post to include my html markup.

Comment: So in a nutshell. I would like the popup to open after 10 seconds on page load. but if the user navigates from the page or click the close button ("x"), even if the user refresh the page the popup should not appear. it should only appear once per user. Thanks a lot for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the cookie in the `close_box` function but you are not testing for that cookie anywhere else in the code.

```
    //This function open the box after 10 seconds. 
   if ($.cookie("lightbox") != 'true') { 
     setTimeout(function () {
        $('.lightbox').ready(function () {
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
                'opacity': '.50'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.box').animate({
                'opacity': '1.00'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block')
        });
       }, 10000);
    }
```

This should prevent the box from opening at all if the cookie is set to `true`.

Comment: The way your answer is currently written, it will do the opposite. It will only create the lightbox if the cookie is set to true.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Thanks for the catch! Edited to remove the logic error.

Comment: oh thanks Justin I have edited my original post and what i would like this popup to do is:  I would like the popup to open after 10 seconds on page load. but if the user navigates from the page or click the close button ("x"), even if the user refresh the page the popup should not appear. it should only appear once per user. Thanks a lot for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just opening a box on timeout, check cookies first:

```
// global timer variable 
var g_Timer;

// check popup already showed
  if ($.cookie("lightbox")  === null)
  {
    g_Timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('.lightbox').ready(function () {
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
                'opacity': '.50'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.box').animate({
                'opacity': '1.00'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block')
        });
    }, 10000);
  }
```

Use [clearTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) method to stop timer if page is about to be unloaded:

```
$(window).on('unload', function() {
  clearTimeout(g_Timer);
});
```

Then your close function may look like this:

```
function close_box() {
    clearTimeout(g_Timer);

    $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
        'opacity': '0'
    }, 300, 'linear', function () {
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none')
        $(".box").hide().trigger('click');

        $.cookie("lightbox", true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I tried this it still wont open my pop up. I have provided the complete html in my original post.

Comment: thanks max. I have edited my original post and what i would like this popup to do is: I would like the popup to open after 10 seconds on page load. but if the user navigates from the page or click the close button ("x"), even if the user refresh the page the popup should not appear. it should only appear once per user. Thanks a lot for the effort –

Comment: In such a case, you could use clearTimeout method on your 10 seconds timeout to prevent it from firing. I updated my code above.